# Why I can not unset array in associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, unset

Why I can not unset array in associative array php
I see the dump but Also I see unseted arrays in final array

```
foreach($dossier['program'] as $program){
    foreach($program['cities'] as $city){
        foreach($city['services'] as $service){
            foreach($service['featureds'] as $key=>$featured){
                dump($key);
                if($key!==(int)$quotation_conditions['groups']){
                    dump($service['featureds'][(string)$key]);
                    unset($service['featureds'][(string)$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dd($dossier);
```

Comment: Because arrays passed to `foreach` by value.

Comment: I dont understand, How I need to unset?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Please write the code How I need to do

Comment: @David please give it a go it's a very simple change if you just read the manual...

Comment: So I need to use unset(&$featured)?

Comment: Because that's like trying to kill yourself by stabbing your reflection in the water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($dossier['program'] as &$program){
    foreach($program['cities'] as &$city){
        foreach($city['services'] as &$service){
            foreach($service['featureds'] as $key=>$featured){
                dump($key);
                if($key!==(int)$dossier['groups']){
                    dump($service['featureds'][(string)$key]);
                    unset($service['featureds'][(string)$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understand Thanks